# All shortest paths in a graph using K reverse edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-layering

Let's say i have a directed graph G(V,E) with positive integer weights at it's edges.What i need to do is find the shortest paths between all vertices using at most K(integer) reverse edges.What i mean by that is:If we are at edge u and there is only a directed edge from v to u we can use it as long as we have not used K reverse edges for this path.This has to be implemented in C++ and give the shortest paths as a result.

I thought about running dijkstra V times(something like Johnson's algorithm)but i am not sure how to take advantage of the reverse edge property.Any ideas?

Comment: This question might be better asked in the https://cs.stackexchange.com/ portal.  Also, it's not clear what you mean by K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common approach to problems like this is usually described as "layering".  You (conceptually) make *K*+1 copies of the graph, *G*<sub>0</sub> to *G*<sub>*K*</sub>, and then connect a vertex *u*<sub>*i*</sub> in *G*<sub>*i*</sub> to a vertex *v*<sub>*i*+1</sub> in *G*<sub>*i*+1</sub> if there is an edge from *v* to *u* in *G*.

A path from *s*<sub>0</sub> in *G*<sub>0</sub> to *t*<sub>*i*</sub> in *G*<sub>*i*</sub> then represents a path from *s* to *t* in *G* that uses *i* reverse edges, where *i* is at most *K*.

You can just use Dijkstra's algorithm on this new layered graph.

When you get used to this you can think about it in an even simpler way: you just use Dijkstra's algorithm, but instead of having states in the queue like [reached *v*, with cost *c*], you use states like [reached *v*, with cost *c*, having used *i* reverse edges].  Often, when we use Dijkstra's in real life, there is no actual graph given, so it helps to think of it as a search through states and their transitions.

Comment: In G_1 we have used 1 reverse edge in G_2  2 etc.I think this is the solution thank you!