# Finding walk from s to t of length divisible by 3 in directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

From [Jeff Erickson's lecture notes](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/book/05-graphs.pdf) on graph algorithms, there is an exercise to check whether a walk between given vertexes `s` and `t` can be divisible by 3 in a directed graph.

What I thought is to use breadth-first search on the graph to get all paths from `s` to `t`. If the simple paths don't have lengths divisible by 3, run the algorithm again to check if there is a cycle between `s` and `t` where the length of cycle is not divisible by 3. However, I feel the method is really inefficient.

It would be great if you have any good suggestion about this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754866/all-shortest-paths-in-a-graph-using-k-reverse-edges/54755487#54755487

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This kind of question can often be solved by changing the graph and applying a standard algorithm, instead of changing an algorithm.

In this case, we can create a new graph with three copies of each node, so e.g. if `u` is a node in the original graph, then the new graph has three corresponding nodes `(u, 0)`, `(u, 1)` and `(u, 2)`. For each edge `u → v` in the original graph, the new graph has three corresponding edges `(u, 0) → (v, 1)`, `(u, 1) → (v, 2)`, and `(u, 2) → (v, 0)`.

Given a walk `(n_0, r_0) → ... → (n_k, r_k)` with `k` edges, we know that `r[i+1] = r[i] + 1 (modulo 3)`, because all edges in the new graph satisfy that property. Therefore if `r_0 = 0` then `r_k = k (modulo 3)`.

It follows that `(s, 0)` has a walk to `(t, 0)` in the new graph if and only if `s` has a walk to `t` in the original graph using a multiple of 3 edges. So you can just apply a standard path-finding algorithm like BFS in the new graph to see if `(t, 0)` is reachable from `(s, 0)`.

Note that if you have to actually implement this as code, it is not necessary to actually build the new graph as a data structure; it is an [implicit graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_graph).